# Is it possible to test that an Action is Unreachable via a URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I am using MvcContrib to write unit tests against our routing table in an MVC3 project. So far so good.

I would like to ensure that an action is only accessible "within" the application and that it cannot be routed to using a URL. The implementation is using the `ChildActionOnly` attribute to prevent access to this. I can test this manually and it works but is it possible to write a unit test that asserts that this URL is inaccessible?

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of anything in MVCContrib TestHelper allowing to achieve this. You could always use reflection to test the presence of this attribute on the corresponding controller action.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_action_on_home_controller_is_a_child_action_only() 
{
    Expression<Func<HomeController, ActionResult>> ex = c => c.Index();
    var mce = (MethodCallExpression)ex.Body;
    var atts = mce.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChildActionOnlyAttribute), false);
    Assert.IsTrue(atts.Length > 0);
}
```

Comment: Like the implementation. But you've made me think about what I really want. I don't like the idea of testing for the presence of a method attribute and yet clearly that is what I was asking in my original question.  I'll amend the question in the light of this. Cheers.